# Stack does not exist error on ec2 instance but working fine on local

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, spring-boot, amazon-sqs, spring-cloud

I am getting below exception and I am not getting any solution to solve the problem. Also, in case you want to know, I am using amazon cloud sqs dependency in my gradle file. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/aws/autoconfigure/context/ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Stack for i-123d410f does not exist (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: cc12e6b5-805e-11e5-9847-a3f73a9dcc2f)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean]: Factory method 'stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Stack for i-123d410f does not exist (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: cc12e6b5-805e-11e5-9847-a3f73a9dcc2f)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 99 more
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Stack for i-123d410f does not exist (Service: AmazonCloudFormation; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationError; Request ID: cc12e6b5-805e-11e5-9847-a3f73a9dcc2f)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1078)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:726)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:461)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:296)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.AmazonCloudFormationClient.invoke(AmazonCloudFormationClient.java:1273)
    at com.amazonaws.services.cloudformation.AmazonCloudFormationClient.describeStackResources(AmazonCloudFormationClient.java:1023)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.autoDetectStackName(AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.java:63)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.afterPropertiesSet(AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.java:53)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.<init>(AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.java:44)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.<init>(AutoDetectingStackNameProvider.java:48)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.core.env.stack.config.StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean.<init>(StackResourceRegistryFactoryBean.java:57)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration.stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean(ContextStackAutoConfiguration.java:63)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$baf59de0.CGLIB$stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean$0(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$baf59de0$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c9d0ffe4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at org.springframework.cloud.aws.autoconfigure.context.ContextStackAutoConfiguration$StackAutoDetectConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$baf59de0.stackResourceRegistryFactoryBean(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 100 more
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After struggling, I solved above exception by putting ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class in exclude of EnableAutoConfiguration, like for example:

```
...
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = ContextStackAutoConfiguration.class)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not understand this,  can you please elaborate?

Comment: Alternatively, configuring `cloud.aws.stack.auto=false` should also work

Comment: @cavpollo Thanks a lot, Can you please put your comment as answer, it worked for me